# Build Scan not working for Gradle in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am following the Gradle tutorial on https://guides.gradle.org/building-android-apps/ . So the last step of this part is Run a Build Scan. I am doing the exact same thing as it asked me to do, but Android Studio keeps saying "Error:(14, 0) Could not get unknown property 'com' for root project 'HelloWorldGradle' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Here is my Top-level build file(build.gradle(Project: HelloWorldGradle)):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all        sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha7'
        classpath 'com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:1.7.1'
    }
}  

apply plugin: com.gradle.build-scan

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the following line in your `build.gradle`:

> apply plugin: com.gradle.build-scan

You need to update as

```
apply plugin: 'com.gradle.build-scan'
```

Another thing you need to pay attention is ALWAYS put the `com.gradle.build-scan` plugin as the very first one, like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.gradle.build-scan'
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Otherwise, you would see this:

> WARNING: The build scan plugin was applied after other plugins.     The
>   captured data is more comprehensive when the build scan plugin is
>   applied first.
>
> Please see https://gradle.com/scans/help/plugin-late-apply for how to
>   resolve this problem.

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 8):

My issue was solved after writing the following in build.gradle the top-level file for the project

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.16'
}

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
    publishAlways()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Edit in May 2020:**

Now in May 2020, the way to do it is, add the following to the app gradle file:

```
plugins {
  id "com.gradle.build-scan" version "3.3"
}

buildScan {
    termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'     
    termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'                                   

    publishAlways()                                               
}
```

You should place these outside of the `buildscript { .. }`, e.g., right after it, rather than inside it.

Then the build scan, e.g., with `./gradlew build --scan`, should work.

**Edit in October 2019:**

The current (October 2019) way to get the build scan working is to add the following to the app gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '2.4.2'                     
}

buildScan {
    termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'     
    termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'                                   

    publishAlways()                                               
}
```

and it would probably be best to get it directly from the [gradle build scan user manual](https://docs.gradle.com/build-scan-plugin/) in the future for when it changes again.

Answer (score 3):

According to [gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.com/build-scan-plugin/), this should be the latest implementation

```
    plugins {
            id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '2.3'   
    }

    buildScan {
            termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'     
            termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'                                   

            publishAlways()                                                
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run from Terminal next command `./gradlew build --scan` or `gradlew build --scan`

Also, agree to the Terms of Service in the command line.